# JasperReports - non-standart transparent header bar

Tags: jasper-reports

The question is very simple - now in my report (based on Jasper) I have the blocks with header bars like the simple rectangles, which get the their color as the parameter.

Current view:

[image]

My task is the save the transparent property of this header bar and transform it to the next view:

[image]

Is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: `My task is the save the transparent property of this header bar and transform it to the next view` - What do you mean? Your pictures look like an identical - What is a difference?

Comment: Difference in the top right corтук of rectangle.